# Reply to an outbound email sent from a Case record create a new case, as opposed to attaching to the Case in which the email was sent?

Tags: email, apex-email-service, email2case

I am using sales force email services and email to case . It works fine for routing email , But when I used OWD email addresses and an outbound email , Then on user reply it results in creating a new case rather  as opposed to attaching to the Case in which the email was sent.

Kindly let me know , What could be a possible solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to a 'bug' in the email-to-case processor and the way that Saleforce generates thread-ids that was introduced in the Winter'16 release. Some of it is explained in this known issue - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008a5dAAA - but what I found to be the root of the error is that when you call the email page (EmailAuthor) if you pass an 18 character SFID, it generates the thread ID that is placed into the subject and/or body of the outgoing email that includes the extra 3 characters that make up the end of the ID. When a reply comes back into email-to-case, it does not understand the thread id (because of the extra 3 characters), so it does not know that this is a reply and creates a new case.

I am working with SF support to get this documented as a bug at this time.